# How to expand an iSCSI lun with targetcli on CentOS7?

Tags: linux, centos, iscsi

I have a CentOS 7 machine with iSCSI configured. see ls output from targetcli below. I want to add disk02 to lun0 so that to the iSCSI client can see a total 869.16GB instead of 392.2GB

Question: Is it possible to have lun0 use the combined capacity of disk0 and disk1 and if so how to do that with targetcli on CentOS7.

```
/> ls
o- / ....................................................................................................... [...]
  o- backstores ............................................................................................ [...]
  | o- block ................................................................................ [Storage Objects: 2]
  | | o- disk01 ...................................................... [/dev/sdb4 (392.2GiB) write-thru activated]
  | | o- disk02 ..................................................... [/dev/sda (476.9GiB) write-thru deactivated]
  | o- fileio ............................................................................... [Storage Objects: 0]
  | o- pscsi ................................................................................ [Storage Objects: 0]
  | o- ramdisk .............................................................................. [Storage Objects: 0]
  o- iscsi .......................................................................................... [Targets: 1]
  | o- iqn.2014-08.com.exmaple:nuc .................................................................... [TPGs: 1]
  |   o- tpg1 ................................................................................ [gen-acls, no-auth]
  |     o- acls ........................................................................................ [ACLs: 0]
  |     o- luns ........................................................................................ [LUNs: 1]
  |     | o- lun0 ..................................................................... [block/disk01 (/dev/sdb4)]
  |     o- portals .................................................................................. [Portals: 1]
  |       o- 0.0.0.0:3260 ................................................................................... [OK]
  o- loopback ....................................................................................... [Targets: 0]
/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The creation of an iSCS target LUN links the previously-defined storage objects with the target and defines which number the device will use.

Therefore, if you want the LUN (`lun0`) to be expanded, then the underlying storage object (`disk01`) needs to be expanded.

One method to do this is to create a logical volume from the two disks as follows (although this will require an outage):

*Delete the unused storage object `disk02` and create a logical volume from it:*

```
/backstores/block> delete disk02
Deleted storage object disk02.
/backstores/block> ls
o- block ...................................................................................................... [Storage Objects: 1]
  o- disk01 .............................................................................. [/dev/sdb4 (392.2GiB) write-thru activated]
/backstores/block>
```

*Create a logical volume (`iscsi_lv01`) using the entire device:*

```
$ pvcreate /dev/sda
  Physical volume "/dev/sda" successfully created
$ vgcreate iscsi_disk01 /dev/sda
  Volume group "iscsi_disk01" successfully created
$ lvcreate iscsi_disk01 -l 100%FREE -n iscsi_lv01
  Logical volume "iscsi_lv01" created
```

**Note:**
Clearly if the existing device was formatted and contained data then this new volume will have to be formatted and the data copied onto it.

*Create a new storage object using the new volume:*

```
$ targetcli
/backstores/block> create iscsi_lv01 /dev/iscsi_disk01/iscsi_lv01
Created block storage object iscsi_lv01 using /dev/iscsi_disk01/iscsi_lv01.
/backstores/block> ls
o- block ...................................................................................................... [Storage Objects: 2]
  o- disk01 .............................................................................. [/dev/sdb4 (392.2GiB) write-thru activated]
  o- iscsi_lv01 .................................................... [/dev/iscsi_disk01/iscsi_lv01 (476.9GiB) write-thru deactivated]
/backstores/block>
```

*Recreate `lun0` using the new volume*

```
/> cd iscsi/iqn.2014-08.com.exmaple:nuc/tpg1/luns/
/iscsi/iqn.20...nuc/tpg1/luns> delete lun0
Deleted LUN 0.
/iscsi/iqn.20...nuc/tpg1/luns> create /backstores/block/iscsi_lv01
Created LUN 0.
/iscsi/iqn.20...nuc/tpg1/luns> ls
o- luns .................................................................................................................. [LUNs: 1]
  o- lun0 ........................................................................ [block/iscsi_lv01 (/dev/iscsi_disk01/iscsi_lv01)]
/iscsi/iqn.20...nuc/tpg1/luns>
```

*Delete the existing storage object `disk01` to then be added to the volume group:*

```
/> cd backstores/block/
/backstores/block> delete disk01
Deleted storage object disk01.
/backstores/block> cd /
/> ls
o- / ......................................................................................................................... [...]
  o- backstores .............................................................................................................. [...]
  | o- block .................................................................................................. [Storage Objects: 1]
  | | o- iscsi_lv01 .................................................. [/dev/iscsi_disk01/iscsi_lv01 (476.9GiB) write-thru activated]
  | o- fileio ................................................................................................. [Storage Objects: 0]
  | o- pscsi .................................................................................................. [Storage Objects: 0]
  | o- ramdisk ................................................................................................ [Storage Objects: 0]
  o- iscsi ............................................................................................................ [Targets: 1]
  | o- iqn.2014-08.com.exmaple:nuc ....................................................................................... [TPGs: 1]
  |   o- tpg1 ............................................................................................... [no-gen-acls, no-auth]
  |     o- acls .......................................................................................................... [ACLs: 0]
  |     o- luns .......................................................................................................... [LUNs: 1]
  |     | o- lun0 ................................................................ [block/iscsi_lv01 (/dev/iscsi_disk01/iscsi_lv01)]
  |     o- portals .................................................................................................... [Portals: 1]
  |       o- 0.0.0.0:3260 ..................................................................................................... [OK]
  o- loopback ......................................................................................................... [Targets: 0]
```

*Save the new configuration in case `auto_save_on_exit` is not set to true:*

```
/> saveconfig
Last 10 configs saved in /etc/target/backup.
Configuration saved to /etc/target/saveconfig.json
/> exit
Global pref auto_save_on_exit=true
Last 10 configs saved in /etc/target/backup.
Configuration saved to /etc/target/saveconfig.json
```

*Extend the existing logical volume with the original device `disk01`:*

```
$ pvcreate /dev/sdb4
  Physical volume "/dev/sdb4" successfully created
$ vgextend iscsi_disk01 /dev/sdb4
  Volume group "iscsi_disk01" successfully extended
$ lvextend -l 100%VG /dev/iscsi_disk01/iscsi_lv01
  Extending logical volume iscsi_lv01 to 869.1GiB
  Logical volume iscsi_lv01 successfully resized
$
```

**Note:**
There will also be the additional step of resizing the filesystem once `disk01` has been added if the volume required formatting.

*Notice the new sized storage object:*

```
/> ls
o- / ......................................................................................................................... [...]
  o- backstores .............................................................................................................. [...]
  | o- block .................................................................................................. [Storage Objects: 1]
  | | o- iscsi_lv01 .................................................. [/dev/iscsi_disk01/iscsi_lv01 (869.1GiB) write-thru activated]
```

Unfortunately this method requires down time while the lun is resized, however, following this method will ensure it is kept to a minimum.

**References**

[Targetcli Wiki](http://linux-iscsi.org/wiki/Targetcli)
[iSCSI target guide using tgtadm](https://web.archive.org/web/20150316071825/http://www.gurkulindia.com/main/2013/04/rhel-6-iscsi-administration-series-configuring-iscsi-server-and-client/)